# Debug uWsgi application in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, uwsgi

I would like to debug an uWsgi application in Eclipse. Is there a way to create a run profile in Eclipse so that it can attach the debugger to the uWsgi python interpreters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some way by using the [pydev remote debugger](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html):

- in the code you want to debug `import pydevd`
- at the point you want to break call `settrace`
- start your uwsgi container
- start the pydev remote debugger (see link)
- make a http call executing your code in uwsgi
- et voile. Breaking.

code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/eclipse indigo/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300/pysrc/")
import pydevd

def application(env, start_response):
    #break here
    pydevd.settrace()
```